# Error: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to CustomAuthenticationToke

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

**HI.**

Please help anyone who has encountered this problem.

I want to run an [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-extra-login-fields) Custom Project Setup.
In class CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider in line 3:

```
 public class CustomUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {
...
1 @Override
2    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

3        CustomAuthenticationToken auth = (CustomAuthenticationToken) authentication;
```

I get an error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to secyriry.authentication.loginpassworld.CustomAuthenticationToken

Сhecking gives false

```
  if(auth instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken){ //auth=null
            auth= (CustomAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        }
```

I understand the error but I can't understand it

1. Why this solution was applied
2. How to fix the situation

[sreen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daJ3P.png)

[sreen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjytr.png)

---

*I translated everything using GOOGLE*

Comment: Is CustomAuthenticationToken extending from UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken ? `public class CustomAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`

Comment: welcome to stackoveflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Is CustomAuthenticationToken extending from UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken ? public class CustomAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken - Yes.         Everything works, I found the reason, it was not turned on correctly .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter (), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class), the response was https://leaks.wanari.com/2017/11/28/how-to-make-custom-usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter-with-spring-security here.